# Get Current user's account type, domain id

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How to get current user's account type, whether it is Production or Sandbox, and also the domain id.
I tried using
`var output = url.resolveDomain({
        hostType: url.HostType.APPLICATION
})`
but it is throwing TypeError Cannot read property 'APPLICATION' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `N/runtime` module to get this information:

```
var accountId = runtime.accountId;
var environment = runtime.envType;  // PRODUCTION, SANDBOX, etc.
```